# Django Many-To-Many filtering

Tags: python, django, orm

Assume the following set of models:

```
class A(models.Model):
  pass

class B(models.Model):
  pass

class M2M(models.Model):
  a = models.ForeignKey(A)
  b = models.ForeignKey(B)
```

A way to **filter** (this is a part in the chain of a larger application) by some conditions on the links, in naive Django ORM is to do this:

```
def fun():
  as = A.objects.filter("some complex queryset") 

  m2ms = M2M.objects.filter("some complex B-dependent QS")

  return as.filter(id__in=[m.a_id for m in m2ms])
```

But obviously this produces a rather awful query "id__in", and clearly executes as two queries.

Is there a better way to get Django to produce a proper join?

Comment: Voting to close as "typographic error" as you have obviously not read the Django documentation, or tried any solutions of your own as Many-To-Many relationships are (and have been) supported in Django 1.3 since 2012

Comment: I somewhat disagree, even if accept your RTFM sentiment. Firstly, Django documentation is not terribly clear on the fact if M2M relationships work in the case where they are not explicitly declared as ManyToManyField(through='M2M'), secondly, it's still a valid, specific question even if answered in the manual (readability), and thirdly, an important part of the skillset is also knowing how to ask a question and where asking a question is more efficient than blind experimentation or exploring the dusty corners of a manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be able to achieve this in a single query. For example, lets say you want to filter only those records which have a value greater than 50 on field `x` in the model `B`, you would do:

```
A.objects.filter("some-filter-criteria", m2m__b__x__gt=50)
```

You can read more on [related name lookups here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: While the works, the actual solution is to not try and recreate a Many-to-Many relationship, and just use the `ManyToManyField` in the DjangoORM.

Comment: I don't understand where the relationship creation is recommended in the answer.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that this approach actually generates identical queries as the explicit `ManyToManyField`?

Comment: It does. But an explicit m2m gives you some additional utilities like signals, etc..

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly declare a many-to-many field from A to B through M2M.

```
class A(models.Model):
  bs = models.ManyToManyField('B', through='M2M')
```

Now you can simply do:

```
A.objects.filter(condition_on_A='foo').filter(b__condition_on_b='bar')
```

Comment: I think you are on to a very helpful hint here but I wish you would give more details.